# How can I hide my inputs when printing my webpage?

Tags: javascript, html, css, printing, media

I am using the script below:

```
<script>
function printpage()
{
window.print()
}
</script
```

To call it after with this:

```
<input type="button" value="Print this page" onclick="printpage()" />
```

But I don't know how to insert in the script this:

```
$('input' )
.hide();
```

Meaning that all the input from the print area is hidden.

Any ideas?

Comment: You need a '.' infront of the input to get all input classes using jquery.

Comment: `function printpage(){
$('input' ).hide();
window.print();
}`

Comment: not working , now i cant print

Comment: @c0d3Junk13 Using `$("input")` gets all `<input>` elements...Their input element doesn't have a class anyways

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can solve this using CSS by specifying the media type as `print`:

```
  <style type="text/css" media="print">
/*<![CDATA[*/
    input{
        display:none;
    }
  /*]]>*/
  </style>
```

Comment: +1 , I didnt know that you can specify `media` like this. I always use `@media`

Comment: when i put this in my css file , thw only thinkg tha it do is hide my input before pressing the print

Comment: Are you sure you've removed the Javascript code that hides your inputs? CSS is not hiding your inputs on your desktop - your Javascript code is.

Comment: yes  i am sure when i put this in my css file i cant see the inputs

Comment: i put the above into my <head> and now i can see the inputs but i can print them too

Answer (score 3):

Use @Media CSS rule:

```
@media print {
  input {visibility:hidden;}
}
```

or

```
@media print {
  input {display:none;}
}
```

The choice between these options depends on your page flow: display:none removes the input completely, while visibility:hidden simply hides it, but it still occupies its place.

You don't need to hide it in JavaScript.

Comment: not working , where should i put this, i put it in my css and is not working